# How to access c++ header file in python files(.py)

Tags: python, c++

I am import from c++ header file into python .py file.can i access the c++ header file #define into python

In python code,

```
import sys

sys.path.import
```

I am expected #define's value in running python code
It get name error

Answer (score 4):

You can't just `import` a C++ header into a Python program - they're different languages so it won't work.  It's much more complicated than that, see [Extending Python with C or C++](https://docs.python.org/3.7/extending/extending.html).

If you just want to pick out `#define`'s from a C++ header file could could simply open that file in your Python program and search for lines that begin with `#define` and parse the variable and value. Something like:

```
import re
defines = {}
with open("header_file.h") as header_file:
    for line in header_file.readlines():
        if line.startswith("#define"):
            line.rstrip()
            m = re.search('#define\s+([A-Za-z]\w+)\s+(.*)', line)
            if m:
                defines[m.group(1)] = m.group(2)
```